# PATHINFO_EXTENSION not working when sent over JSON

Tags: php, json, react-native

I have the following code:

```
$filename = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = strtolower($ext);
$thefilename = $videoid.'a.'.$ext;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],$doc_path.$upload_dir.'/'.$thefilename))
```

Which was working fine when posting a video through a browser, but I have now built an app in React Native, which uploads the video etc fine, however, it's not getting a value for $ext so it's just uploading 'filename.'.

Comment: What does `var_dump($filename, pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))` give?

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry for my ignorance, but how would I use var_dump in the JSON call from within the app?

Comment: Are you sure it even has an extension?

Comment: @RoAchterberg in the app in React Native it's defined as an mp4. After it's uploaded (without the extension) if I add mp4 at the end of the filename, it plays perfectly.

Comment: Well I guess you could `var_error_log` it then check the error logs. https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/writing-to-the-php-error_log-with-var_dump-and-print_r/